# create histogram with bins in react js

Tags: python, reactjs, histogram

How to create a histogram with bins in **react** js similar to the way in Python.

in Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [2,5,11,22,66,88]
plt.hist(x, bins =3)
plt.show()
```

and the result is a histogram- in x axis: 3 ranges of x values(3 in the num of bins that I sent). y axis: the number of values from x that are in each range.
I add the histogram result that I got in Python.
[image of histogram python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXDLX.png)
So, how to do the same in React?
Thank you!!

Comment: If you are trying to translate matplotlib to javascript, use `d3.js` or similar plotting library, instead. It wont be "similar" because the APIs are different

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plotly.js library for this.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.3.0.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
const x = [2,5,11,22,66,88]

const trace = {
    x: x,
    type: 'histogram',
    xbins: {
        end: 88, 
        size: (88 - 2) / 3, 
        start: 2  }
  };
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [trace]);
```

I've created a simple code pen, please take a look [there](https://codepen.io/MatadorVirtuoz/pen/ExmMVEg) for details. There should be no problem to do the same in React settings.